# value_to_boolean deprecated; what's a good replacement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, deprecated

Is there a "cool-kid-approved" replacement for `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean` in rails 3.2?

Comment: Can you give a use case, or some more details? You can always use `!!` which would change any value to a boolean. Eg. `!!nil` would be false, and `!!1` would be true.

Comment: While `[false, 0, '0', 'f', 'F', 'false', 'FALSE'].map { |v| !!v }` yields `[false, true, true, true, true, true, true]`. It's obviously not a replacement.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In Rails 4.2, this looks like a possible way to do it:

```
 ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database(value)
```

Which under the covers is going to do this

```
if value == ''
  nil
else
  ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES.include?(value)
end
```

Or in Rails 5:

```
 ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)
```

Which seems to end up here:

```
  def cast_value(value)
    if value == ''
      nil
    else
      !FALSE_VALUES.include?(value)
    end
  end
```

Comment: It seems like `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user(value)` would be a more appropriately named alternative (with the same functionality) https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/value.rb#L33

Comment: For Rails 5, today I had to do ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast rather than type_cast.

Comment: Thanks, will update.  I haven't been on Rails 5 for a bit.

Comment: ` ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)`

Comment: There's a little gotcha: `value_to_boolean` used to convert nil to false, `type_cast_from_database` does not (it returns nil in that case). This can lead to errors if you have eg. non-null constraints.

Comment: Beware if you're converting symbols, as `:''` is cast to `true` (I'm converting a boolean column that can be nil to a localized string).

Answer (score 11):

As jokklan mentioned in the comments, the answer depends on what you want to do with it? Do you want to accepts all kinds of strings and turn them into a real boolean? Or do you control the submitting end as well and can you be more strict?

From strict to more magic:

#### bang bang

The double bang method converts any object to a real boolean. The first bang turns it into it's opposite, the second to it's proper boolean value.

Basically, `nil` and `false` will become `false`, everything else will become `true`.

```
!!nil     # => false
!!false   # => false
!!0       # => true
!!true    # => true
!!""      # => true
!!"false" # => true
!![]      # => true
```

Good for exporting to json, but not really needed when kept inside Ruby.

#### Object#present?

From ActiveSupport and the opposite of `blank?`:

```
nil.present?     # => false
false.present?   # => false
0.present?       # => true
"false".present? # => true
"".present?      # => false
[].present?      # => false
```

#### Array#include?

Specify special strings that are falsy, or truthy to you:

```
not [nil, false, 0, '0', 'f', 'F', 'false', 'FALSE'].include?(value.presence)
```

Or the other way round:

```
[true, 1, '1', 't', 'T', 'true', 'TRUE'].include?(value)
```

These are handy if you are handling form submissions with checkboxes, or handling external input and you want to be more lenient. You can of course decide for yourself what you want to accept.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. Looks like `!!` was the syntactic sugar I was looking for....

Comment: Just in case it wasn't apparent from iain's answer, if you want string `"false"` to return boolean `false` when using `!!`, as in `!!"false"`, it will not. Instead it'll return `true` and you'll have a yucky bug to find. If you're in rails really only checking for presence, as iain's answer would, you're really better off using more explicit `#present?` or `#blank?` methods from Active Support Core Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database(value)` return nil if the value is nil/empty('').

`ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database(nil) # => nil`
`ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database('') # => nil`

I would prefer `!!` with `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database(value)` for converting input value to boolean

`!!ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database(nil) # => false`
`!!ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database('') # => false`

Comment: Thanks for the QA!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `value_to_boolean` isn't really deprecated in Rails 4 http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Column.value_to_boolean

Comment: I think it's not deprecated but they added stopdoc to the class which I assume it implies it's for internal use only.

Comment: its removed in Rails 4.2